# Смена фонового изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть 3 изображения и div

```
<div style="background-image: url ("fon.jpg")">
</div>
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
```

как сделать чтобы при клику по изображению менялось фоновая картинка div? с возвратом назад через некоторое время

Comment: Изменение фона должно происходить на ту картинку, на которой кликнули. 
то есть - при клике на 1.jpg - background-image у div  должен быть 1.jpg
при клике на 2.jpg - background-image у div  должен быть 2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.img').click(function(){
 $("#z").css("background-image","url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
})
```

```css
#z{
  width:430px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ccc;
 }
 
 img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="z">
</div>
<img class="img" src="http://apia.exp0.in/public/upload/news/tn_v_kieve_dron_kurer_dostavil_pervuyu_posilku_14359152901812_image.jpg">
<img class="img" src="http://lamcdn.net/lookatme.ru/post_image-image/gFMFp8YUjBZihF9sdPc7TA-article.jpg">
<img class="img" src="http://www.3dnews.ru/assets/external/illustrations/2015/05/19/914308/cicada-drone.jpg">
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
$('.img').animate({'opacity':'0'},600,function(){
  $(this).css('background-image':'url(image2.jpg)');
  $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
});
```

Comment: а вызов не подскажете?

Comment: Изменение фона должно происходить на ту картинку, на которой кликнули. то есть - при клике на 1.jpg - background-image у div должен быть 1.jpg при клике на 2.jpg - background-image у div должен быть 2.jpg

Comment: <img src="1.jpg" onclick="????"> 
я в джаве почти 0

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк Java и JavaScript - разные языки программирования. `onclick=""` (да и вообще inline-JS) использовать не стоит.

Comment: @Regent я понимаю разницу между ОО-языком Java и JavaScript. Насчет inline-JS - с точки зрения правильного программирования не стоит использовать, но мне для сайта-одностраничника на чистом HTML главное результат) Спасибо за советы, здесь (на сайте) хотя-бы можно чему-то научиться, и все делятся опытом и знаниями.